# Playing around with certificates in .net5

Tags: bouncycastle, x509certificate2

I am trying to learn about certificates, the need for that is from an idea I had a few days ago to simplify the ordering and delivery of SSL certificates to my collegues. So I startet to investigate "how hard can it be"?

And to large entusiasm, the entire process was "not so hard", but then I came to "generating pfx certificates", with private key...

The code is from a console test app:

**Creating keys and storing it.**

```
int keysize = 2048;
CngKeyCreationParameters ckcParams = new CngKeyCreationParameters()
{
   ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport,
   KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.None,
   KeyUsage = CngKeyUsages.AllUsages,
};

ckcParams.Parameters.Add(new CngProperty("Length", BitConverter.GetBytes(KeySize), CngPropertyOptions.None));

CngKey myCngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, KeyName, ckcParams);

byte[] privatePlainTextBlob = myCngKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
string privateblob_string = Convert.ToBase64String(privatePlainTextBlob); 
// Now I can save the Pkcs8PrivateBlob "somewhere"
```

Later I can pick up this up and create a Certificate Request and send it to a certificate service by API.

```
byte[] cngbytes = Convert.FromBase64String( privateblob_string );
CngKey importedkey = CngKey.Import(cngbytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob, CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider);
RSACng rsa = new RSACng(importedkey);

request = new CertificateRequest(
   new X500DistinguishedName(order.CertName),
   rsa,
   HashAlgorithmName.SHA512,
   RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

etc....
```

Now I can download the issued certificate in various formats from the API.
So far so good. Now I want to create PFX file and KEY file.

**Creating PFX:**

```
// My issued certificate from provider
byte[] PublicKeyStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CER_STRING);

// pfx
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(PublicKeyStr, string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
byte[] certificateData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password");
// Now I have the pfx, but no private key
```

I am obviously is not capable of solving this. I have been on a journey into Bouncy Castle, with no luck (btw: where is their documentation?).

I have noticed that .net5 has a metode that I thought (again) might solve this.
X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(ReadOnlySpan certpem, ReadOnlySpan keypem)
But then I need to get the keypem "private key pem".

My question is simple: Have I totally misunderstod or is the any way to add the needed private key to the pfx file with the information I have stored from the CngKey?

ANY suggestions, ideas, help, tips will be very welcomed. It is simply so frustrating to be so close and just fail miserably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate the public certificate with the private key before exporting it as a PFX.

```
// Key
byte[] cngbytes = Convert.FromBase64String( privateblob_string );
CngKey importedkey = CngKey.Import(cngbytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob, CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider);
RSACng rsa = new RSACng(importedkey);

// Cert
byte[] PublicKeyStr = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CER_STRING);
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(PublicKeyStr);

// Together:
X509Certificate2 certWithKey = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);

// PFX:
byte[] pfx = certWithKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, pwd);
```

Comment: Fantastic. I will look into CopyWithPrivateKey. Thanks.

Comment: It all came back to me now. 
"System.Security.Cryptography.Cng" throws "Operation is not supported". 
NB: The text "Operation is not supported" is translated by me and I am using .net5.

Comment: Ah, right, you have a non-named key, so it needs to export it, but it’s not exportable. Try `RSA.Create()` and `rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(cngbytes, out _)`, which is an exportable version.

Comment: Sir, you have been very helpful. I surfed on your previous work and assistance you have given on the community and I am amazed over your skills, patience and teaching skills. Again, thank you for your help.